# 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return a non-null value of the same type - on EF API Call

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to populate an `int` property of a class in a .NET Core 3.1 API Controller (using Entity Framework Core) with the below code:

```
[HttpGet("Get")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Partner>>> Get()
{
     List<Device> devices = await _context.Devices.ToListAsync();
     List<Partner> items = await (from p in _context.Partners
               select new Partner
               {
                Id = p.Id,
                Name = p.Name,
                FiscalCode = p.FiscalCode,
                Licenses = p.Licenses,
                Erp = p.Erp,
                ErpName = p.Erp == 1 ? "Erp 1" : "Erp 2",
                Devices = devices.Count(k => k.PartnerId == p.Id)
                }).OrderBy(k => k.Name).ToListAsync();

      return items;
}
```

The `Devices = devices.Count(k => k.PartnerId == p.Id)` line generates the following error:
`System.InvalidOperationException: When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return a non-null value of the same type`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return a non-null value of the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59682297/when-called-from-visitlambda-rewriting-a-node-of-type-system-linq-expression)

Comment: @Progman Nope, or at least I haven't found any relevant connection between my issue and that

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions. Also explain what you are trying to read and what the `Devices` property in `Partner` do  or supposed to be.

Comment: The devices property is an integer. I just want to count some items based on a criteria. Nothing fancy

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do a **join** and **group by** in database. In this way you are just query one time in database, so **better performance**.

Try this:

```
List<Partner> items = await(from p in _context.Partners
                                    join d in _context.Devices
                                        on p.Id equals d.PartnerId
                                    group d by d.Partner /*relation property*/ into g
                                    select new Partner
                                    {
                                        Id = g.Key.Id,
                                        Name= g.Key.Name,
                                        DeviceCount=g.Count()
                                        // select other your properties here
                                    }).OrderBy(k => k.Name).ToListAsync();
```

But if you want to continue to what you were doing which is not recommended, try putting the **Partner** table in memory then select data from these in memory tables.
like this:

```
var partners=await _context.Partners.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: thank you. This seems to be the right track with a few changes. I need a left join instead of inner and a syntax that would generate a COUNT(d.Id) instead of the current COUNT(*)

Answer (score 0):

What you trying to do is inner joining them and it's better to let the EF handle it:

```
var partners =  from partner in _context.Partners
                join device in _context.Devices on partner.Id equals device.PartnerId into devices
                select new Partner()
                {
                    Id = partner.Id,
                    Name = partner.Name,
                    FiscalCode = partner.FiscalCode,
                    Licenses = partner.Licenses,
                    Erp = partner.Erp,
                    ErpName = partner.Erp == 1 ? "Erp 1" : "Erp 2",
                    Devices = devices
                };
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Amirhossein, but I don't want a join, since that would multiply the lines. The devices property is an integer, representing a count and not a list of items